# Mulesoft Anypoint Studio will not let me connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, pom.xml, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I continue to get a error saying:

> Error trying to load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver : Cannot load class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver':
> Class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/s-claims'

I have the dependency for it in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have the shared library in the pom:

```
<sharedLibrary>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
</sharedLibrary>
```

When trying to connect directly to SQL Server using the same credentials, I am successful.

I am fairly new to Mulesoft so It could be something simple I am missing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a Mulesoft configuration issue, not connectivity or authentication related. Have you checked for your issue in the [Mulseoft help center](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/)?

Comment: What is SQL Server version that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Can you share the complete pom? it should have been working if the pom is correct IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was just a issue with the studio. I didn't change anything and tested my connection again and it worked after redeploying.